# Force Notepad++ To Uppercase Non-Selected Text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

In Notepad++, I have the UPPERCASE shortcut mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in the shortcut mapper. However, this shortcut only works if text is selected. For example, let's say I have the text "dog" and I place my cursor left of the "d". If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, nothing happens. It's only when I select the "d" that the shortcut works. Is there any way to force Notepad++ to uppercase the "d" even though it's not selected?

Comment: The upper case function only works on selected text - that's how it was designed.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good candidate for the Notepad++ macro feature.

Record the following steps (Macro menu → Start Recording):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
- Edit menu → Convert Case To → UPPERCASE

Then stop recording (Macro menu → Stop Recording) and save the macro (Macro menu → Save Current Recorded Macro). You can then define some combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and another key to run your macro whenever you want.